# Binomial where N value is too big

Tags: binomial-distribution

It is estimated that 20% of students take an active part in a sports club in college. If 20
students are randomly sampled and asked if they are active participants in a college
sports club what is the probability that more than 4 are active in a sports club?

So I am setting this up as a binomial and finding '1 - (p(0)+p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4))'

However the N value is 20. Is there a simpler way of determining this?

Comment: You can just compute p(0), ...., p(4) by hand.

Comment: but for example 20!/3!(17!) = 1.14x10^33  ...how do I get around these massive numbers?

Comment: If you calculate this with a calculator do not forget to put braces around (3!*17!).

notice that 20! = 20*19*18*....*1, and 17! = 17*16*...*1. So dividing them gives: 20!/(17!*3!) = (20*19*18)/(3*2*1) = 10*19*6.

Comment: I am an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why N=20 is bothering you.
Hopefully you got these:

$P(0)=\begin{pmatrix}20\\0\end{pmatrix}0.2^00.8^{20}$

$P(1)=\begin{pmatrix}20\\1\end{pmatrix}0.2^10.8^{19}$

$P(2)=\begin{pmatrix}20\\2\end{pmatrix}0.2^20.8^{18}$

......


You'll have to use calculator anyway.

Comment: I was incorrectly using my calculator. Thanks